# how to exit from script if heredoc command is failing

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, heredoc

I have a ssh heredoc in my shell script, if one of those commands in heredoc is getting error how do i exit from my shell script.

my shell script will be like this

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

loginto_vm() {

    ssh host@IP << ENDSSH

ls n1n

cd n1n

ENDSSH

    echo 'done'

}

loginto_vm
```

here it is exiting from ssh heredoc if "n1n" is not there and printing echo statement, but i want it to exit from script

Comment: !/bin/bash

set -o errexit loginto_vm() {

ssh host@IP << ENDSSH

ls n1n cd n1n ENDSSH echo 'done' }

loginto_vm

Comment: cd should return non-zero, so ssh should return non-zero and you would expect the semantics of `set -o errexit` to cause the script to abort.  However, `set -o errexit` is known to have unexpected behavior in many old shells, and there are undoubtedly edge cases in modern shells, and you really ought to avoid it.  Just do `ssh host@IP << ENDSSH || exit`

Answer (score 3):

You can check the exit status of any critical command in your heredoc and exit the ssh with an error - then check the ssh exit status to exit your script

```
ssh host@IP <<ENDSSH
ls n1n || exit 1
cd n1n || exit 2
ENDSSH
(($?)) && exit 1
echo 'done'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can instruct the shell to exit if anything errors like in any shell script:

```
$ sudo su <<EOF              
set -e
echo before
bad-command
echo after
EOF
```

Output:

```
before
sh: line 3: bad-command: command not found
```

Notice `after` isn't printed.

Comment: So simple but effective

Answer (score 0):

The commands in the here decument are executed by a remote shell. You need to pass in `set -o errexit` inside the here document in order for it to be visible there; it is entirely separate from the shell which runs the `ssh` command.